# Issue with npm installation of firebase-tools - Stuck during installation

Tags: npm, command-line-interface

[this is happening when i try to install Firebase CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiOyR.png)

I've been facing an issue with the npm installation of firebase-tools. The installation process seems to be stuck, and I've been unable to resolve it after trying the following steps:

Checked internet connection stability.
Used a different npm registry mirror.
Cleared npm cache using npm cache clean -f.
Updated Node.js and npm to the latest versions.
Attempted to install firebase-tools locally using npm install firebase-tools.
Tried using Yarn for installation.
Despite these efforts, the installation process is still not completing, and it's stuck at [#########.........] / idealTree: timing idealTree Completed in 34075ms.

Environment details:

Operating System: window 10
Node.js version: v18.16.0
npm version:9.5.1
Any guidance or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Same here! For me it's stuck at `idealTree:morgan: sill placeDep node_modules/firebase-tools on-finished@2.4.1 OK for: body-parser@1.20.2 want: 2.4.1`

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to initial your npm 'NPM INITIAL'

Comment: I don't think initial is a valid command for NPM. Maybe you meant `npm init`? But still, this shoudln't be the cause of the issue.